# Simulating Mouse events in other window using websockets(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, websocket

Here what I am trying to achieve is , to make a websocket program in which if a user "mousedown + mousemoves" in a window same event is triggered in the other browser window.

So here is what I have done so far:

**Client Side JS Code:**

```
 var clicking = false;
 $(document).mouseup(function(){
         clicking = false;
       });

 $('#canvas').mousedown(function(e){
       clicking = true;
       var ww= e.pageX;
       var mm = e.pageY;
     
('#canvas').mousemove(function(event){ 
      if(clicking === false) 
         {  
      var msg = { //sends data
     w:'',
     m:'',
     type:"simple",
     x:event.pageX,
     y:event.pageY,
     name: myname,
     color : '<?php echo $colours[$user_colour]; ?>'
    };
         }
else{
var msg = {
    w:'ww',
    m:'mm',
    type:"move", 
    x:event.pageX,
    y:event.pageY,
    name: myname,
    color : '<?php echo $colours[$user_colour]; ?>'
    };
        }
 
 websocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));   
 
 
 });
});
```

**Now Server side Code for handling data:**

```
    $tst_msg = json_decode($received_text); //json decode 
$user_name = $tst_msg->name; //sender name
$typ = $tst_msg->type;       
$m = $tst_msg->m; //clickcoordinates
$w = $tst_msg->w;
$x = $tst_msg->x;// coordinates
$y = $tst_msg->y; // y-coordinate (user)
$e = $tst_msg->ev;
        //prepare data to be sent to client
if($typ == "move"){
        $response_text = mask(json_encode(array('me'=>$m,'we'=>$w,'ev'=>'moving','type'=>'usermsg', 'name'=>$user_name,  'x'=>$x,'y'=>$y)));
         send_message($response_text); //send data
         }
    else{
        $response_text = mask(json_encode(array('me'=>$m,'we'=>$w,'ev'=>'simple','type'=>'usermsg', 'name'=>$user_name,  'x'=>$x,'y'=>$y)));
        send_message($response_text); //send data
        }
```

Now this code is handled by client in JS in following way :

```
websocket.onmessage = function(ev) {
     var msg = JSON.parse(ev.data); //PHP sends Json data
     var wwx = msg.we;
     var mmx = msg.me;
     var ex = msg.ev;
     var uname = msg.name; //user name
     var xx = msg.x;
     var yy = msg.y;
    
     if(!(uname== "<?php echo $_COOKIE['name'];?>")){
    if(ex=="moving"){
    eone = $.Event('mousemove');
    eone.pageX = xx;
            eone.pageY = yy;
    etwo = $.Event('click');
    etwo.pageX = wwx;
            etwo.pageY = mmx;
    $(document).trigger(eone).trigger(etwo);
    
    
    }
```

This code is not triggering anything tho.Any ideas? what might be a workaround?

Comment: not enough data, please state where it gets stuck.  does the message get sent? does it reach the other side? do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: well the problem is in the line "$(document).trigger(eone).trigger(etwo);" for some reason it isnt working..... i tried removing it from the code and then alerting with the coordinates and code worked fine but when i added it back , it dint alert .....What might be stopping from event to trigger? and can we trigger multiple events like this?

Comment: you probably have this one figured out by now, but if not, I would try to reduce your problem to a simple jsfiddle which moves the mouse to a specific point and triggers a click.  If this does not work, then all the rest of the post is irrelevant and is just noise, you'll have much better success at getting a response.